# Which popular games are the most mathematical?

Tags: big-list, soft-question, recreational-mathematics, game-theory

I consider a game to be mathematical if there is interesting mathematics (to a mathematician) involved in

- the game's structure,
- optimal strategies,
- practical strategies,
- analysis of the game results/performance.

> Which popular games are particularly mathematical by this definition?

---

**Motivation**: I got into backgammon a bit over 10 years ago after overhearing Rob Kirby say to another mathematician at MSRI that he thought backgammon was a game worth studying. Since then, I have written over 100 articles on the mathematics of backgammon as a columnist for a backgammon magazine. My target audience is backgammon players, not mathematicians, so much of the material I cover is not mathematically interesting to a mathematician. However, I have been able to include topics such as martingale decomposition, deconvolution, divergent series, first passage times, stable distributions, stochastic differential equations, the reflection principle in combinatorics, asymptotic behavior of recurrences, $\chi^2$ statistical analysis, variance reduction in Monte Carlo simulations, etc. I have also made a few videos for a poker instruction site, and I am collaborating on a book on practical applications of mathematics to poker aimed at poker players. I would like to know which other games can be used similarly as a way to popularize mathematics, and which games I am likely to appreciate more as a mathematician than the general population will.

Other examples:

- go
- bridge
- Set.

**Non-example**: I do not believe chess is mathematical, despite the popular conception that chess and mathematics are related. Game theory says almost nothing about chess. The rules seem mathematically arbitrary. Most of the analysis in chess is mathematically meaningless, since positions are won, drawn, or tied (some minor complications can occur with the 50 move rule), and yet chess players distinguish strong moves from even stronger moves, and usually can't determine the true value of a position.

To me, the most mathematical aspect of chess is that the linear evaluation of piece strength is highly correlated which side can win in the end game. Second, there is a logarithmic rating system in which all chess players say they are underrated by 150 points. (Not all games have good rating systems.) However, these are not enough for me to consider chess to be mathematical. I can't imagine writing many columns on the mathematics of chess aimed at chess players.

**Non-example**: I would exclude Nim. Nim has a highly mathematical structure and optimal strategy, but I do not consider it a popular game since I don't know people who actually play Nim for fun.

---

To clarify, I want the games as played to be mathematical. It does not count if there are mathematical puzzles you can describe on the same board. **Does being a mathematician help you to learn the game faster, to play the game better, or to analyze the game more accurately?** (As opposed to a smart philosopher or engineer...) If mathematics helps significantly in a game people actually play, particularly if interesting mathematics is involved in a surprising way, then it qualifies to be in this collection.

If my criteria seem horribly arbitrary as some have commented, so be it, but this seems in line with questions like [Real world applications of math, by arxive subject area?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2556/real-world-applications-of-mathematics-by-arxiv-subject-area) or [Cocktail party math](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5450/cocktail-party-math). I'm asking for applications of real mathematics to games people actually play. If someone is unconvinced that mathematics says anything they care about, and you find out he plays go, then you can describe something he might appreciate if you understand combinatorial game theory and how this arises naturally in go endgames.

Comment: Yeah, well the rules of mathematics are chessly arbitrary.

Comment: I think it's a mischaracterization to say chess is nonmathematical; it's just that chess, like so many things one encounters in the real world, is neither elegant nor simple from the point of view of mathematics.  That game theory can't tell us much about chess tells us more about the limitations of game theory than about the mathematical nature of chess.  That said, your suggested examples are definitely better.

Comment: This borders on subjective, argumentative, and discussion-y.  I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: -1 this is a terrible question. i do not understand why the asker is interested in answers this question, which is essentially 'give a list of games'

Comment: This is very far from 'give a list of all games.' One hope is to find other popular games whose play involves mathematics. Another is to learn more real mathematics about games I already know. A third idea is to see what resonates with other mathematicians. I'm sorry if you don't find these interesting, or if you find my criteria arbitrary--I don't see a huge difference between this and questions like, "What are neat applications of mathematics/this field?" 

Comment: -1 for arbitrariness. You're welcome to your beliefs about chess and nim, but they're far from universal, and make for a less useful question.

Comment: You disagree with my statement that Nim is not actually played for fun? I can show you go clubs, bridge clubs, backgammon clubs, even a "world championship of rock-paper-scissors," etc. I've never seen a Nim club or heard someone describe himself or herself as a Nim player. There are many theoretical games people don't actually play, and I don't think it's arbitrary to exclude those. I'll clarify my reasons for excluding chess later.

Comment: mathematics also helps to understand some basic prinicples of chess like opposition and other stuff like this.

Comment: The question is somewhat imprecise, because the answers below show there is no clear, agreed-upon notion of what a game is, exactly. 

Comment: In "l'année dernière à Marienbad" ("last year in Marienbad"), 
a movie by Alain Resnais, you can see people playing Nim for fun.
Now this just moves the problem, because I don't know anyone watching that movie for fun. (I just mean that peculiar movie. Resnais made a lot of very good movies. But that one is a serious contender for the prize of the most boring movie ever).



Comment: I've been meaning to watch that movie for fun for quite a while now... might have to reconsider!

Comment: Max Euwe showed using the Thue-Morse sequence that the rules of chess in his time did not exclude the possibility of an infinite game. I'd say that's interesting mathematically.

Comment: The rules of chess evolved so as to produce an interesting game. Nonetheless, rigorous theorems and proofs are possible in endgame theory, and anything with proofs of important facts would seem to be mathematical by definition. I think the OP should have said, mathematical but where the mathematics is not well-motivated from a pure math point of view.

Comment: @Gene Ward Smith: I didn't intend that restriction. If it takes mathematical sophistication to establish results which are important in chess, that would make chess mathematical by my definition. The results I have seen either do not require mathematics or are not important in chess, but if you know of others please share them.

Comment: @Joël: Certainly your opinion is well founded, but just for the record, I find *Marienbad* one of the most interesting and compelling movies I have ever watched. As for "fun", it was as much fun for me as was learning about p-adic Lie groups. Quite a lot -- in a way.

Comment: @Torsten: You're opinion is certainly well-founded too. And today, Resnais is dead, and he was one of my favorite filmmaker, so I like all his movies.

Comment: Just in case you haven't... I suggest you search in Martin Gardner's formidable books and/or his articles in the "Scientific American" magazine. You'll find a great deal of "mathematical games",mathematical properties of games, mathematical studies of games, etc.

Comment: The dual question is also intriguing: which proofs of  mathematical theorems have a structure that resemble the most a strategy of a game?

Comment: While I agree with the statement that the game itself is far from matching any mathematical model well enough, I'd like to mention a very interesing book by Bonsdorff/Fabel/Riihimaa: "Schach und Zahl" (Chess and Numbers). It discusses a number of problems such as enumerations, longest and shortest sequences of moves, placements, where combinatorics and other branches of mathematics need to be applied. Apparently there's no English translation.

Comment: Related to this question: https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2884

Comment: @MarkMeckes I would like to point out that Combinatorial Game Theory(CGT) has tools to study games such as chess (though chess is not a combinatorial game). They got better results than people expected; it did not get much attention due to AlephChess's performance. As as sidenote, CGT is very successful in studying the game dots and boxes.

Answer (score 94):

[**Set**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28game%29) is a card game that is very mathematical.

[image: 12 Set cards]

Set is played with a deck with $81$ cards. Each card corresponds to a point in affine $4$-space over $\mathbb Z/3$, with $3$ possible colors, shadings, shapes, and counts. The players must identify Sets, sets of $3$ cards corresponding to collinear points. Sets are also triples of cards which [add up to the $0$-vector](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7881/sum-of-n-vectors-in-mathbb-z-nk/13025#13025). The three cards pictured form a Set.

A natural question which arises during play is how many cards you can deal out without producing a Set. There can be $9$ cards in a codimension-$1$ subspace which do not contain a Set, corresponding to a nondegenerate conic in affine $3$-space such as $z=x^2+y^2$. There can be [at most $20$ cards not containing a Set](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/D.Maclagan/papers/set.pdf), corresponding to a nondegenerate conic in the projective $3$-space containing $10$ points.

Lest anyone think it is "just a game", this has led to [quite a bit of research](https://www.quantamagazine.org/set-proof-stuns-mathematicians-20160531/), including applications to computational complexity of matrix multiplication.

Comment: Here's an online version for people wanting to see what it's like:
http://setgame.ath.cx/

Comment: Does this satisfy the "popular" criterion?  I haven't exactly seen many Set clubs around.

Comment: It is at least popular enough that Set decks can be found in big-box bookstores like Borders or Barnes & Noble.

Comment: I've seen people playing Set in public places a few times.

Comment: Set is very popular with certain types of student clubs (e.g. math clubs), although I don't think it's really the kind of game that warrants its own clubs. 

Comment: Set is usually a hit at parties (coming from an undergraduate at a school that ranks in the top party schools in the US.)

Comment: It's worth noting that the $n$-dimensional extension of the "natural question" described at the end of the post here (i.e. how large can a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_3^n$ not containing a line be) is a major open question in additive combinatorics, sometimes referred to as the "cap set problem".

Comment: The previous link setgame.ath.cx is gone, though this http://www.setgame.com/set/puzzle seems to be working

Comment: I like to play Set, but I usually lose against my children, because of my coulour-blindness. For people like me, the three colours should be something like Blue, Red (or Green, equivalently) and Yellow. The problem is even worse with the Dwarves and Dice game.

Comment: You pictures nine cards.

Comment: This was the first game that first came to my mind, when I read the title. However, it looks like that the OP was thinking in a slightly different direction.

Answer (score 71):

[**Hex**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_(board_game)) is a popular game with some interesting mathematical properties. John Nash gave an easy proof that the first player can force a win, his famous "stealing strategies" argument. His proof gives no indication as to what the optimal strategy actually looks like.

There is also a nice AMM paper by David Gale in which he shows that the fact that Hex can not end in a draw is equivalent to the Brouwer fixed point theorem (for higher dimensions, one needs a higher dimensional version of Hex).

[image: 11x11 Hex board]

One variant is called [**Y**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_(game)). Both players attempt to create a group connecting all sides of a triangular board. As with Hex, there are no ties possible. A commercial version adds 3 points of positive curvature, with 5 neighbors instead of 6.

[image: Commercial version of Y]

Comment: I wonder: would it be possible to define a Hex analogue on the heptagonal or octagonal tiling of the hyperbolic plane?

Comment: @Eriek Any progress on that thought? ‎

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler Yes, not hard to do. You can just play it on an embedding of the hyperbolic plane, like a Poincare disk. I found a way to play it on graph paper that (seems to) preserve the mechanics of the hyperbolic version: http://hexandoct.net16.net. Turns out Bill Taylor discovered an equivalent game he called "Quickway" prior to me. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rec.games.abstract/dhDKiR1edBk/JqIAz9wZaakJ

Comment: @Eriek Making diagonal connections on a square grid is very different from octagonal tiling of the hyperbolic plane.

Answer (score 56):

**[Dots and boxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_and_Boxes)** is a pencil-and-paper game with a reasonably deep mathematical theory.  The game is often played by schoolchildren.

Comment: One thing interesting about Dots and Boxes is that it can often be well approximated by Nimstring which itsef can be mapped onto Nim. So the theory of Nim is important even if Nim itself isn't that interesting.

Comment: FWIW, at a very high level of play on a small board, nim theory is surprisingly irrelevant. Dots and boxes is a very mathematical game, but nim is only one component of it, and there are plenty of expert-level players on a 5x5 board who know nothing at all about nim but who will still wipe the floor with anyone who has read Winning Ways and assumes that they are now an expert. See for example http://www.littlegolem.net/jsp/forum/topic2.jsp?forum=110&topic=69 , a discussion which is visibly (a) mathematics and (b) relevant to dots and boxes, but (c) has nothing to do with Nim.

Comment: It's mentioned in the Wikipedia article, but it may as well be mentioned again: Elwyn Berlekamp wrote a book on the mathematical theory of dots and boxes. 

Comment: There's also http://wccanard.wetpaint.com/ .

Answer (score 55):

This was a favorite pass time on my mobile.
Its pushing blocks also known as Sokoban:

[image]

Some years ago it came as a little surprise
to me that it is NP complete. Here is one paper
saying that:

Demain, E.D. and Hoffmann, M.
Pushing Blocks is NP-Complete for Noncrossing Solution Paths, 2001
https://people.inf.ethz.ch/hoffmann/pub/dh-pbnns-01.pdf

Best Regards

Comment: Actually, Sokoban has been proved to be PSPACE-complete by J. Culberson: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~joe/Preprints/Sokoban/index.html. 
The paper by Demaine and Hoffman seems to consider several different variants of the game; moreover, they only show NP-hardness.

Some more references:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_complexity#Complexities_of_some_well%2Dknown_games

David Eppstein's webpage: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/cgt/hard.html

Comment: Well, it is no surprise that Sokoban is NP-complete. Most games people care to play are PSPACE-hard (let alone NP-hard) but may not be in NP. Similarly, most puzzles (non-mathematical) people are interested in are NP-hard.

Answer (score 48):

**The game of Go** is mathematical in several ways. Its rules involve connected sets of pieces rather than pieces. Many combinatorial games including infinitesimals can be represented as positions in go endgames, as was described in [Mathematical Go: Chilling Gets the Last Point](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eberlek/cgt/gobook.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [xmp.net](http://senseis.xmp.net/diagrams/43/88b3fdd02b849b49818e153dd2e17910-thumb.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Though I love Go, I can't agree that it has a mathematical feel except in the endgame.  Set and Sudoku both seem to use the same sort of "proof" process that we're already used to; with the exception of Go endgames and perhaps complex ko fights, I rarely have the familiar "proving / deriving" feeling during a game.

Comment: I think many of the ideas which you can prove in the go endgame (before infinitesimals) are present but too complicated to prove in much earlier stages. In addition, the connectivity fights in go seem like they should give you that feeling of proving elementary statements. You sometimes want to prove that you can connect one group of stones to another provided that there is no enemy stone added to a particular area. The smaller the area, the less you need to worry about that connection. 

Comment: go is so complex! clearly, it is mathematical, but my favorite part is its organic nature that openings and middle game take or feel like.

Comment: Go is interesting from the computer science point of view because it is very far from solved. Checkers is solved, and chess has been "solved" from a practical point of view - computers beat the best humans. Will this happen with Go? And when computers start beating pros, will moving to a larger board regains the advantage for humans?

Comment: Artificial intelligence in go involves a lot of statistical learning, which requires nice mathematics. Also I want to believe that there is something mathematical like an "influence function", which would give the influence of each player at each location and relies on geometric considerations.

Comment: Bu the way i've been thinking for a long time to a "continuous version" of go, where you can play anywhere on the field (not just at intersections).

There would be some rules to modify but the overall seems more natural to me. Unfortunately I don't have the skills to program it, would someone be interested?

Comment: This already exists as a game at least, there's a page about it on Sensei's Library for example (http://senseis.xmp.net)

Comment: @Raphael Lachieze-Rey: Many years ago, I worked out rules for playing go on a general point-set topological space, which includes some version of "continuous go": http://www.segerman.org/topologo/

Comment: One way to measure the complexity of a game is by declaring that Person 1 is someone who knows only the rules of the game, and that Person n+1 is someone who will beat Person n 90% of the time; then, the complexity is the maximal such chain. I've heard (though I can't remember where) that chess is 5 and go is 9. I'd imagine that this measure of complexity is correlated with how well we can program computers to play the game, although (presumably interestingly, from a psych point of view) there are probably cases where this doesn't match up perfectly.

Comment: @Aaron Mazel-Gee: There are big problems with this measure of complexity. Mixing luck in with skill does not cancel the skill, but it can decrease this measure of complexity to below 1. In the other direction, replacing a game with a best-of-n match does not change what it takes to learn to play the game, but it increases that measure of complexity.

Comment: @Pait Yes, it's happened. And I doubt that moving to a larger board will help, since AlphaGo exploits the translation invariance of the rules (by using convolutional neural networks).

Comment: I see that my comment is from almost 5 years ago. Nevertheless, it happened far faster that I would have imagined - the progress seems to have come all in the last year, when AlphaGo started beating the previous best programs by several stones. It's incredible. 

@AdamP.Goucher, if someone had made a statement such as "moving to a larger board will not make a different because the software uses neural networks" a year ago, I would have said he drank the Kool Aid ;-) That is not no longer appropriate.

Comment: While some aspects of the game are translationally invariant there is usually a huge difference between the value of a group (essentially connected set) of stones on the 3rd line versus the 4th line, and that value changes dramatically even if you change from $19 \times 19$ to $23 \times 23$. On a larger board, the center makes up more of the possible territory, for example. If you change the size of the board, you need to reconsider all of the moves that trade influence in the center for territory on the side. So, I think convolutional neural networks help less than you might expect.

Comment: @Pait: While there was a significant jump, I wouldn't say that most of the progress was made in the last year. I think a lot of people didn't want to admit how much progress other go programs made before that. The other computer programs were playing at the top amateur/lower professional levels earlier. Before AlphaGo, go programs played better than all but about 100 players in North America, and although NA is not the strongest region that was still a huge accomplishment.

Comment: There was a big jump in the prospects of go programs when they started using randomized rollouts about 10 years ago. One key point is that rollouts parallelize well, and computing power is improving primarily through increased parallel power rather than faster processors. Of course, you need the parallelizable algorithm to work, which was not obvious then, and many people dismissed adding randomness to deterministic games at that time. (I proposed it for chess earlier, and few people agreed with me.)

Comment: Thanks @DouglasZare for your interesting comments! Have you or would you care to collect your thoughts and ideas in a blog post or position paper? 

I still would say that AlphaGo changed the paradigm from randomized tree search to position evaluation by pattern recognition, which seems very significant to me. You clearly know much more than I do and it would be very instructive to read more.

Comment: @Pait: I wrote about the progress in go before AlphaGo in a column for GammonVillage, which requires a subscription, but I think I could send you a copy. I haven't looked at the details of AlphaGo except that I am familiar with deep learning and some of the techniques they used which are analogous to those used in backgammon. I don't know how they dealt with ko fights, for example, and that could be quite important. It was the main obstacle to me to applying deep learning to go.

Comment: Neat! More adequate to move this offline, I'm pait@usp.br

Answer (score 42):

Believe it or not, [Battle Ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game)) is an interesting mathematical game. Well, at least if you play it in high enough dimension: *Finding small explicit sets that hit all large enough combinatorial rectangles* (ships) has been studied quite a lot and there are still a couple of open problems. See for instance, [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01200907).

Comment: Many children's games are surprisingly mathematically interesting. These games typically have very simple rules and very little scope for player strategy. This means that that the entire evolution of the game can be described by simple rules, which in turn means that the game can be treated mathematically. Even games like War and Candyland, which have no player strategy whatsoever, lead to interesting math.


Answer (score 40):

The ability to *embed* mathematical problems into chess (like combinatorial game theory into go) should not be underestimated.  Papers by [Richard Stanley](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/chess/queue.pdf) and [Noam Elkies](https://www.emis.de/journals/EJC/Volume_11/PDF/v11i2a4.pdf) demonstrate problems where the objective is to determine the number of ways to perform a given task.  They include problems where the answer is

- A Catalan number, say the 7th or even the 17th.  (Problems A and B from Stanley.  Problem A from Elkies.)
- Fibonacci numbers, arbitrarily large.  (Problem 4 from Elkies.)
- The coefficients of the Maclaurin series for tangent, say the 7th or 9th.  (Problem D from Stanley.  Problems B and 1 from Elkies.)
- Directly computable from the Selberg integral $\int_0^1 \cdots \int_0^1 \prod_{1\le i\lt j\le 4} (x_i - x_j)^2 dx_1\cdots dx_4 $.  (Problem E from Stanley.)

Of course, the answers are this for some mathematical reason, not accidentally.  Many of the problems are also elegant from a chess perspective.

Comment: I have seen some problems they have constructed, however, the ones I have seen do not follow the normal objectives of chess, which is quite different from the connections between go and combinatorial game theory.

Comment: Let me add that I am impressed by their ability to embed interesting problems in a game I still view as not mathematical. 

Answer (score 37):

There's also the famous [Rubik's Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube), which is popular and heavily maths-related.

Comment: But is that considered a *game*? 

Comment: Rubik Cube has already been suggested (cannot add comment due to rep), although do not see why this is not a game, nevertheless lets just quote a couple of studies on the group theory of Rubik Cube [Group Theory and the Rubik’s Cube](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~jjchen/docs/Group%20Theory%20and%20the%20Rubik%27s%20Cube.pdf) and [The Mathematics of the Rubik’s Cube](http://web.mit.edu/sp.268/www/rubik.pdf) Thanks

Comment: Solving the Rubik's cube may be considered a one-player game. There are also many people who compete in speedcubing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedcubing

Comment: To add to Douglas's comment, solving rubik's cube in fewest possible moves(FPM) is another event in cube championships, and this is more mathematically interesting.

Answer (score 31):

[**Lights Out**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LightsOutPuzzle.html) is a game which has effectively been reduced to a problem in linear algebra, particularly a routine exercise in Gaussian elimination. A good link can be found [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690705). What's particularly interesting is the fact that operations in the game commute, which allows for the linear algebra approach.

I wonder if there are any non-commutative turn based games which can also be solved mathematically? Certainly, chess is out of the question!

Comment: I gave a talk at MathFest in 2007 on the $n$-dimensional generalization of this game. Just assume your playing the game on a lattice and pressing a light changes all lights touching it.  We also generalized the solution to include things like lights out on a torus or a sphere or a mobius band... The point is, all the solutions are similar and the generalization follows fairly easily by reconstructing the "button vectors" which are related to the change of state when pressing a particular button. 

Comment: I'm not sure about non-commutative turn based games, but certainly the puzzles presented in a number of popular video games can be easily described with non-abelian groups.  One that comes to mind was a lever puzzle in the first God of War game.  The state of a device was manipulated with two levers and a particular state would open the door.  It turns out that the state space of this device was a group generated by the actions of the two levers.  So proceeding in the game was equivalent to finding a representation of a given group element in terms of the generators.

Answer (score 31):

**Poker** is a family of card games.

Many model games from game theory approximate poker situations, and some of the earliest work on game theory featured model games for betting and bluffing in poker (despite the popular misconception that bluffing is not mathematical) studied by [Borel and von Neumann](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etom/papers/poker1.pdf).

Nes Ankeny wrote a book *Poker strategy: Winning with game theory* in 1981 which gives an interesting mathematical approach to poker. Ankeny was a number theorist who was also a world-class poker player.

Tournament poker often rewards lower places than first. This means the value of chips is nonlinear, and several models have been used to determine the appropriate risk aversion by finding good functions from the distributions of chips to probabilities of finishing in each place. One is diffusion, which led to an [application](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etom/papers/poker3.pdf) of the Riemann map of an equilateral triangle, although the difficulty of computing this and higher dimensional diffusion led to the widespread adoption of the independent chip model instead: Shuffle all chips, and rank players by their highest chips. Equivalently, remove the chips from play one by one.

Bill Chen and Jerrod Ankenman wrote *The Mathematics of Poker* aimed more at mathematicians than poker players. They studied model games in which players are dealt numbers from [0,1] instead of cards. They also computed the Nash equilibrium strategies for some situations in NL Texas Hold'em, the most popular variant at the moment. They also addressed a few topics outside of game theory, such as the risk of ruin probability with an unknown but normally distributed true win rate, and with a distribution skewed enough that the Brownian approximation fails, as for tournament play.

When the first few players fold, and we know they are more likely to have folded 8-4 than ace-ace, what can we say about the distributions of hands for the remaining players? Jerrod Ankenman [remarked](http://www.pokerroad.com/forums/showpost.php?p=99242&postcount=29), "the problem of finding the hand distributions of the blinds given that the first n players have folded a specified set of distributions [sets of hands] is NP-hard."

[I merged two answers about poker.]

Comment: See also Alspach's articles:  http://www.math.sfu.ca/~alspach/pokerdigest.html

Comment: Thanks for the references. I'm trying to track down Ankeny's book, since I'm writing a book on practical poker math myself. The Brian Alpach articles I've read are applications of very basic combinatorics, e.g., using inclusion-exclusion to count how often there are k pairs dealt among n players. There is a lot more to poker math than the odds of various deals.

Answer (score 28):

Clay Institute in its lectures on millennium problems list as one of it question ["P vs NP Problem"](http://www.claymath.org/millennium/P_vs_NP/) and simple Minesweeper is listed as example for which finding strategy is equivalent to solution of such problem....which was proved by Richard Kaye referenced below. Here is the [beginning of minesweeper article](http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/minesweeper.pdf):

> The connection between the game and
>   the prize problem was explained by
>   Richard Kaye of the University of
>   Birmingham, England ('Minesweeper is
>   NP-complete', Mathematical
>   Intelligencer volume 22 number 4,
>   2000, pages 9-15). And before anyone
>   gets too excited, you won't win the
>   prize by winning the game. To win the
>   prize, you will have to find a really
>   slick method to answer questions about
>   Minesweeper when it's played on
>   gigantic grids and all the evidence
>   suggests that there isn't a slick
>   method. In fact, if you can prove that
>   there isn't one, you can win the prize
>   that way too.

Answer (score 26):

What about **[Pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_(cue_sports))**?  It contains quite a lot of geometry.

Comment: Especially hyperbolic pool! http://www.geometrygames.org/HyperbolicGames/

Answer (score 26):

Blokus is a fairly new game that's gaining popularity (though there are older games with a similar set-up). There are several versions, and the four-player version has some non-cooperative elements to the gameplay.

Each player takes turns to place polyominoes of size 1 squares through five (the monomino, domino, triominoes, tetrominoes, and pentominoes) so that they touch a previously played piece of their own colour, but only at the corners. The overall aim of the game is to try and cover as much area with your own pieces as possible. The countertactics to stop a player doing this involve placing your pieces in a way that will block them from making good moves.

I think this game would fit your criteria. It is relatively unstudied from a mathematical point of view as far as I know. I imagine some familiarity with some of the mathematical work on tessellations of polyominoes would have to give a player at least a marginal advantage in planning a long-term strategy. It probably fits the criteria in other ways too.

Answer (score 22):

Since you mentioned bridge in the question, but nobody has said anything about it, I'll take a stab. Interestingly, bridge has several more-or-less orthogonal mathematical aspects to it.

1. The play of the hand necessarily involves calculating or estimating probabilities. These are not so difficult as to be mathematically interesting, but I do think they can be slightly more challenging that counting your outs in poker. In bridge there are often multiple possible ways of combining chances to make your contract, some highly dependent for their success upon the order in which the chances are taken.
2. Coming up with efficient communication schemes is central to both bidding and defense. I don't really know enough of the theory behind designing bidding systems to comment. But designing an efficient "relay" system probably involves a smidgen of math.
3. Finally there's more esoteric stuff. For instance, since bridge is not a game of complete information, one doesn't usually expect combinatorial game theory structures to arise. However it can happen that the bidding and play reveal enough information so that everyone knows what cards everyone else has, in which case there is of course complete information.
   Sometimes this actually brings added complexity though! One manifestation of this is [higher order throw-ins](http://www.bridgeworld.com/default.asp?d=esoterica&f=johan.html), which can be analyzed via nimbers, etc.

Comment: I did have a short stub on bridge, but yours is better, so I'll delete mine.

Comment: I understand that Meckstroth and Rodwell, probably the best pair in the US if not the world, once used the Fibonacci sequence in their bidding system.  Never got to ask how…

Comment: Hmm... I've never learned much about this, but some googling (see http://orig.gibware.com/moscito/moscito.pdf) suggests that common to all relay systems is the principle that a bid X permits the transfer of roughly the golden ratio times as much information as the bid X+1 permits. So that would sort of suggest designing your relay system around the fibonacci sequence, except successive EARLY fibonacci numbers are not that THAT close to the golden ratio, and probably it is these early values which would arise most often in actual play. So that might cost your system efficiency.

Comment: I would add two more points:

1. "Restricted choice" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_restricted_choice) is bridge player jargon for Bayes law. I am not sure there is any large community, other than strong bridge players, that contains many high school dropouts and where everyone is able to apply Bayes Law with reasonable accuracy.
(Even bridge players who think of them as less mathematical/analytical would be annoyed to find out they made a play with 60% success rate, when there was one with 70% success rate available.)

Comment: 2. The accepted standard approach to analyzing suit combinations is actually a fairly rigorous game-theoretic approach.
Problem: Given declarer's and dummy's holding in a suit, how should declarer play this suit to get at least x tricks. The assumption is that he has to lead the suit every time (no endplays), and can lead from hand or from dummy at any trick as he chooses (sufficent entries).
Analysis: Find a Nash equilibrium under the assumption that the defenders know declarer's hand, whereas declarer does not know the defenders' hands. The defenders' will often play a mixed strategy.

Answer (score 20):

**[Sprouts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprouts_(game))** is a game contrived by J. H. Conway and M. S. Paterson in the 1960s.

It is an impartial game for two players played on a plane with some spots. Each move consists of both

1. joining two spots (could be the same spot) with a simple curve which does not go through existing spots or curves, such that the degree of each spot after the move does not exceed 3; and
2. placing a new spot on that curve.

Who makes the last move is the winner/loser according to normal/misère play convention.

This game is of topological nature but there are only finitely many inequivalent options at each move, and the game always terminates after finitely many moves (in fact, bounded by number of initial spots), making it an combinatorial game.

It enjoys some popularity, as reflected by the existence of a world association (the [WGOSA](http://www.wgosa.org/), World Game of Sprouts Association).

There are rich graph-theoretic results concerning this game, for example see [this page in NRICH](https://nrich.maths.org/2413) and [this section in *Winning Ways*](http://www.math.uic.edu/%7Ekauffman/Conway.pdf). Experienced players make use of these results to set up goals.

[Here](http://sprouts.tuxfamily.org/) is a website dedicated to the determination of the theoretical winners. A pattern with period 6 emerged under both play conventions. The researchers have published several papers and even considered [Sprouts on general surfaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.0081) ("compact" is not essential, I think), and proved that the theoretical winner of the Sprouts game with a fixed number of spots on different compact surfaces is ultimately periodic in genus, with period 1/period 2 in the case of orientable/non-orientable surfaces.

Comment: Oh, I had completely forgotten about this game. It was a great distraction from classes once upon a time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprouts_%28game%29

Answer (score 19):

**Rock-Paper-Scissors** remains a popular children's game. It's a simple 0-sum game with a mixed Nash equilibrium.

In practice, even if that is your goal, it's hard to generate a uniformly random choice from {rock,paper,scissors} which is independent from what you and your opponent have chosen before. While the unexploitable strategy is simple in theory, exploiting people is complicated, and can involve statistics and hidden-Markov models.

There is an gambling site which lets you play rock-paper-scissors against an opponent, charging a rake so that the Nash equilibrium strategy will lose on average.

Cryptographic issues arise if you want to be confident that a distant opponent's choice was not made with knowledge of yours.

Comment: For what it's worth (i.e. nothing), Rock-Paper-Scissors is a commutative, non-associative magma.

Comment: This game, also known as Roshambo, is surprisingly subtle if you try to design an algorithm that will win a round-robin tournament that includes some intentionally weak strategies.  Exploiting weak strategies without opening yourself to exploitation is a tricky business.  See for example
http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~darse/rsbpc.html

Answer (score 16):

**[Tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe)** and **[Gomoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gomoku)** (five-in-a-row) are common games that have fairly mathematical rules.  Players alternately choose points from some subset of a lattice and try to form a line segment of a certain length.

The [Hales–Jewett theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hales%E2%80%93Jewett_theorem) is a result from Ramsey theory that essentially says that however long the lines must be, a draw is not possible in a sufficiently large dimension.

Gomoku has been solved, constructively.  (The first player wins.)

The game of **[Connect Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four)** adds the additional element of "gravity".  It has also been solved.  (The first player wins on the standard board size, but not on some boards of slightly different size.)

Comment: FWIW, it is widely believed by expert players that connect 4 on an 8x8 board is a win for the 2nd player. Some expert players on the internet have played hundreds if not thousands of games over the last year or two and occasionally lose as player 1, but _never_ as player 2.

Comment: My goto-source for this kind information is the link http://homepages.cwi.nl/~tromp/c4/c4.html which has all boards with width+height <= 15.  However, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Connect_Four#Strategy_for_any_board_size.2C_2D_or_3D claims that 8x8 is known to be a black (second player) win.

Comment: Tic-tac-toe can in fact be mapped: http://xkcd.com/832/

Comment: Can anyone give a reference for the fact that Connect Four has been solved as a first player win?

Answer (score 15):

**Backgammon** is a game of skill and chance.

The doubling cube emphasizes absolute evaluations as opposed to relative evaluations, although it makes some some equities not exist, as the relevant series diverge.

Several areas of backgammon, from determining the appropriate doubling strategy to analyzing the race, are well-approximated by random walks with absorbing barriers.

The analysis of backgammon positions and strategies frequently involves Monte Carlo analysis, variance reduction techniques, and statistics.

Backgammon has been a success for artificial intelligence since neural networks have been able to learn to play at or above the level of the best human players from self-play.

Answer (score 15):

My vote is for the game "Clue".

It's a simple game that young children can learn and enjoy. When they first start playing, they use simple elimination. As they progress they can continue to more advanced strategies. They learn to observe what the other players are asking of each other, who's passing and on what guesses.

Clue may not be a game that adults will play on their own, but when it comes to including the little ones, it's fantastic.

Comment: This one:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluedo  ?

Comment: There is some mathematical analysis of Clue(do) in Chapter 11 of van Ditmarsch and Kooi, One Hundred Prisoners and a Light Bulb.

Answer (score 15):

For some applications of combinatorial game theory to actual chess endgames, see the article by Elkies at https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9905198. For an article I wrote with Elkies on the mathematical aspects of the knight in chess (but with little significance to the actual game of chess), see [https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/knight.pdf](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/papers/knight.pdf)

Answer (score 14):

The game of [Mafia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafia_%28party_game%29), also marketed as Werewolf, depends in practice mostly on how skillful the players are at lying, but there are some fascinating mathematical questions that arise when tries to devise optimal strategies for expert players.  Let me describe one such expert strategy to give the flavor.  In what follows, I will assume basic knowledge of the (simple) rules, which you can find at the above Wikipedia link.

Suppose there is a detective, who secretly learns someone's identity each night.  How can the detective communicate his knowledge without exposing himself to the Mafia?  Each day, each townsperson claims to be the detective, and announces the piece of information he learned the previous night.  The real detective tells the truth, but the Mafia will usually not be able to distinguish the real detective from all the impersonators.  Of course, the townspeople will not know either—until the detective is killed.  Then the townspeople, being expert players with excellent memories, will remember everything the detective said before being killed, and will therefore get a windfall of truthful information that they can they exploit to their advantage.

Many questions arise naturally.  What is the probability that the townspeople win if they use this strategy?  The Mafia have some extra information (they know who they are) and hence if some townsperson makes a false statement while impersonating the detective, the Mafia will detect this and know that that townsperson is not the detective.  So perhaps the detective should lie occasionally to counter this strategy?  How should the townspeople lie?  Should they attempt to give mutually consistent stories or not?  As far as I know, these strategic issues have remained largely unexplored.

See also [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38119/where-to-publish-a-paper-on-the-mafia-game) that announces a mathematical paper on the Mafia game.

Comment: Do you usually play with roles revealed on death? I think Mafia is more interesting if you don't do this precisely because it's easier to fake roles. 

Comment: Qiaochu: Yes, I've always played with roles revealed on death. Taking a quick look at the Wikipedia page, I see that this seems to be the most common way of playing the game.

Comment: We always played without the roles revealed on death.


Answer (score 13):

More puzzles than games, but many of the number puzzles published by [**Nikoli**](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/)  are quite mathematical in nature.  They tend to involve an interplay between local and global conditions that have to be satisfied simultaneously, and one can glimpse geometric and graph-theoretic properties lurking.

The multi-player game [**Carcassonne**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carcassonne_(board_game)) has many of the same aspects, especially the issue of farms separated by roads, which sort of brings in the Jordan curve theorem and a lot of interesting parity issues.

Answer (score 13):

I didn't see mention of Conway's [The Game of Life](http://www.bitstorm.org/gameoflife/). Is it a game? Well, Conway calls it a zero-player game! Other people call it a cellular automaton. You decide.

Answer (score 12):

The game of  [Cootie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cootie_(game)), where players roll dice to collect parts of an insect (cootie), is a variant of the coupon collector's problem.

[image]

Instead of collecting a single instance of each coupon, players must collect multiple copies (6 legs, 2 eyes, 1 head, etc.) to win. It turns out you can compute the expected number of rolls to win at Cootie (even with a weighted die) with a *finite* sum.

In particular, if you have $L$ objects to collect and for each object $\ell<L$ you need $q_\ell$ copies  and the probability of getting the object is $p_\ell$, then the expected number of rolls to get all of the needed objects is

$\displaystyle\sum_{\ell\in L} \frac{{p_\ell}^{q_\ell}}{(q_\ell -1)!}\int_0^\infty x^{q_\ell}\exp(-x) \prod_{k\in L-\{\ell\}}(\exp(p_k x)-\exp_{<q_k}(p_k x))dx.$ `

If you're interested, check out my [paper](https://doi.org/10.37236/906) out for the full computation.

Comment: The French version of te game is "Le cochon qui rit". English translation "The laughing pig".

Answer (score 11):

Call a two player deterministic game *finite* if the game tree has finite depth.  Now we can play...

**Hypergame**:  Player one names a finite game $\Gamma$, for which player two will play the first move.  Play then proceeds as normal, with the winner of $\Gamma$ winning hypergame.

Question: for the first move, can player one choose $\Gamma = \text{Hypergame}$?

Comment: This game is slightly more interesting if player two gets to choose who goes first in Gamma.  As it stands, player one can choose to play the game "first player loses", so player two loses.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that variation.. it makes the question "What is the optimal strategy for player one?" much more interesting!

Comment: Answer: No, because Hypergame is not a finite game.  There are game trees of arbitrarily large depth.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "finite game", I suppose. I didn't mean that there was a uniform bound on the height of the game tree, but rather that there is no infinite sequence of moves. For example, take the game "n" where player one picks a natural number $n$ and play alternates for exactly $n$ moves, with the last player winning. I want to count this game as finite. 

Comment: This is actually the hypergame paradox, a game theoretic version (sort of) of Mirimanoff's paradox on well founded sets. Both answers lead to contradiction.

Answer (score 10):

[Bulls and cows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_Cows) and its modern variant [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)), for which Don Knuth demonstrated that the codebreaker can win in at most five moves. Playing this game with pencil and paper (in a way where both players are codemakers and codebreakers) can be very fun.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten Mastermind, even though I worked on it as an undergraduate. There is a strategy known which takes the minimal expected number of guesses under the assumption that the code is chosen uniformly. That doesn't solve the $2$-player game but it is great progress. The strategy of guessing randomly among the codes consistent with the past information is only off by a fraction of a guess on average, IIRC about $4.7$ instead of $4.4$. I believe I read these results in the Journal of Recreational Mathematics. 

Comment: In a 1995 sci.math article, Mike Wiener announced a solution to the 2-player game with 4 pegs and 6 colors.  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/sci.math/212BmJ5v7y0/UYnteYPwJtoJ
I do not know if anyone has independently confirmed this result. See also *Near-optimal strategies for the game of Logik* by Heeffer and Heeffer.  http://logica.ugent.be/albrecht/thesis/Logik.ps

Answer (score 10):

Peg solitaire which I played on chess board in childhood. Let me explain this solitary game; consider the following table consisted of 33 holes.

There is a peg in all except one of the holes.(Assume that one is in the center). You can move a peg horizontally and vertically. The permissible move consists of jumping one peg over another into an empty hole and simultaneously removing the peg has been jumped over. One can continue this process to reach a situation than cannot have an acceptable move. And the player is winner if the last situation has only one peg.

Thus we can ask some question:

1. Does this play has a winning strategy?
2. What are the possible last situations?

[image]

> The interesting point is the analysis of this game relates to the finite field with 4 elements, GF(4). The answer to question 1 is yes. For question 2 please consult the paper "*[A solitaire game and its relation to a finite field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPpfF.jpg)*" by *N. G. de Bruijin.*

It seems the result of the paper can be extended. I think it is useful in a course in algebra, I exposed the paper when I was a TA in algebra 2.

Comment: There's also a discussion of this game in the beginning of Winning Ways, Volume 4, by Berlekamp, Conway, and Guy.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thank you. I see it, that's interesting.

Comment: Is it intentional that the title of the paper contains a link that goes to a picture? (Probably yes - at least [Scholar Google](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=A+solitaire+game+and+its+relation+to+a+finite+field+Bruijin) doesn't return some link which would be a good replacement.)

Answer (score 7):

In bridge, missing QJxx in a suit, if the Q or J drops on the first round, it is better to finesse if possible on the second round if nothing else is known about the distribution.  This is obvious to a mathematician, but the simple conditional probability is so difficult for the average person that bridge teachers have incorporated the principle into the qualitative "Rule of Restricted Choice", which says that if an opponent plays a card that can be from equals (such as the "quack" from QJ), it increases the probability that the other opponent has the second equal card.

In mathematics we often prove uniqueness before existence.  The one thing I find appealing about Sudoko is that knowing a solution is unique can help in finding the solution.

Comment: Indeed. If you meet someone who understands the "principle of restricted choice", they are almost certainly a mathematician or a bridge player (or both, of course).

Answer (score 7):

There is a popular game in current cellphones called Pixelated (in BlackBerry) or Flood-It (in iPhone) that has a very interesting analysis (its generalization is equivalent to the Shortest superstring problem):
https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.4420
http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Research/Algorithms/BAD10/Slides/Jalsenius.pdf

Comment: The second link seems to be dead.

Answer (score 7):

The Legend of Zelda and several other classic Nintendo games are NP-hard.  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.1895v1.pdf

Following the example of Rubik's Cube (i.e. maybe not exactly a game), as a kid I was fascinated by Spirograph and played it for hours on end.

There is always "Who can name the bigger number" (you can win the computable version (second link below) with large cardinals):

- https://scottaaronson.com/writings/bignumbers.html
- http://web.archive.org/web/20110718091437/http://borcherds.wordpress.com/2007/05/26/my-dad-has-more-money-than-yours/

Pool (aka billiards) has always seemed mathematical to me.  A buddy of mine told me he learned about PDE's from trying to calculate the motion of a ping pong ball (laminar airflow etc).

Enough, I'll stop.

Answer (score 7):

Diplomacy was pretty much invented to illustrate points in cooperative game theory. At least, that's how Martin Shubik told me the story. :)

Actually, I think he invented a card game called "So long, Sucker", and claimed Diplomacy was based on that.

That said, the core points are psychological -- if somebody knows he is losing but has the power to choose the winner, on what basis does he choose?

Comment: If you can choose the winner (other than yourself), you are called the kingmaker. That's a common phenomenon in games with $3$ or more sides. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingmaker

Comment: A more mathematical aspect of diplomacy is the existence of end-game strategies that are not forced wins, but strategies exist with probability p of success for any p<1. See http://uk.diplom.org/pouch/Zine/F1995M/Dreier/Endgame.html and followup articles.

Answer (score 7):

I would be tempted to include [Blackjack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack) in the list of mathematical games.  It's supposedly a game of chance, but gambling establishments routinely forbid card counting, because a mathematical approach to the game gives the player too big of an advantage.  This rule is typically enforced through a mathematical analysis of the player's bets.

Answer (score 7):

[Battle Line](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/760/battle-line) (originally published under the name Schotten-Totten) is a simple 2-player strategy card game designed by noted boardgame designer and math PhD Reiner Knizia. The goal is to try to capture a majority of the flags, which are contested regions where each player assigns troops to try and dominate. It has a number of mathematical elements, the most interesting of which, to me, is that during the course of the game you are allowed to capture a flag at any time that you can prove that your troops will be the strongest possible based on public information (the cards that have been played already).

Answer (score 5):

Well, most card games have mathematical implications, of course.

I'm disappointed at your considering chess non-mathematical. Wonder what Noam Elkies would think. :-)

When I was a teenager I would play a lot a board game named here "Risiko!" (I believe that the English name is "Risk"). My impression then was that there were some mathematical aspects that could be considered while planning a strategy.

(added later)

Also Hex should be added to the list of mathematically interesting games.

Comment: We don't play risk anymore at my house because it always ends in either a verbal argument or a physical confrontation. =\.

Comment: You mention card games. In Cryptonomicon book by Neal Stephenson ( great one!) there is a solitaire card game which gives You a cipher called SOLITARE strong enough to be "industry standard" whilst still may be performed without computer  (only with a card deck only!). It was analysed by Bruce Schneier and this analysis is part of the book!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solitaire_%28cipher%29

Answer (score 5):

[Khet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khet_(game)) is a great new game awarded by Mensa. There is even a master thesis dedicated to it:
http://www.personeel.unimaas.nl/Uiterwijk/Theses/MSc/Nijssen_thesis.pdf

Comment: The link to the thesis seems to be dead - is it suppose to be Nijssen: [Using intelligent search techniques to play the game Khet](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=nijssen+search+techniques+khet)?

Answer (score 5):

StarCraft, a very popular RTS, which is taught at Berkeley.
https://kotaku.com/competitive-starcraft-gets-uc-berkeley-class-5141355

where "Calculus and Differential Equations are highly recommended for full understanding of the course.".

Comment: That class doesn't seem to have anything to do with math

Comment: @DavidWhite: The course description on the website states "Calculus and Differential Equations are highly recommended for full understanding of the course. " Sounds quite math-heavy to me.

Answer (score 5):

There's also [Nine Men's Morris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Men%27s_Morris), which is a very ancient game. My understanding is that it has been effectively solved in recent years with the help of computer analysis.

Answer (score 5):

[Rummikub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rummikub) ?  It encourages some logical thought and analysis.  It seems to have at least one mathematical paper on it<sup>1</sup>

https://doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/bxl033

and it's popular and fun.

<sup>1</sup>D. Den Hertog, P. B. Hulshof, Solving Rummikub Problems by Integer Linear Programming, The Computer Journal, Volume 49, Issue 6, November 2006, Pages 665–669, https://doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/bxl033

Answer (score 5):

The page [https://www.toothycat.net/~hologram/Turing/index.html](https://www.toothycat.net/%7Ehologram/Turing/index.html) claims that the popular trading card game Magic: The Gathering is Turing complete. Some mathematician who knows the rules should recheck the proof.

Answer (score 5):

I’d like to emphasize that typical sports games (eg. played at Olympic games, NFL, MLB, NBA, NHL) often fit at least three criteria mentioned in the question. Before me, Barry Cipra mentioned baseball. These games are very useful to ‘popularize mathematics’, more precisely applied mathematics (operations research). Being a mathematician can help you play the game better (sometimes as a coach because we think of optimal strategies). And ‘mathematics is involved in a surprising way’ as people (students) generally don’t expect mathematics can help in such situations.
The techniques used involve eg. dynamic programming, probability trees, game theory and Monte Carlo methods.
As examples, I could give the following papers:
a)  Beaudoin, D., & Swartz, T. B. (2010). Strategies for pulling the goalie in hockey. The American Statistician, 64(3), 197-204; 
b)  Clarke, S. R., & Norman, J. M. (2012). Optimal challenges in tennis. Journal of the Operational Research Society, 63(12), 1765-1772
c)  Annis, D. H. (2006). Optimal end-game strategy in basketball. J Quant Anal Sports, 2(2).
d)  Kostuk, K. J., & Willoughby, K. A. (2006). Curling's paradox. Computers & operations research, 33(7), 2023-2031.
e)  Chiappori, P. A., Levitt, S., & Groseclose, T. (2002). Testing mixed-strategy equilibria when players are heterogeneous: the case of penalty kicks in soccer. American Economic Review, 1138-1151.
f)  Tibshirani, R. J., Price, A., & Taylor, J. (2011). A statistician plays darts. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series A (Statistics in Society), 174(1), 213-226.

For more on the topic, I recommend (Wright MB. “50 years of OR in Sport”. Journal of the Operational Research Society (2009) 60:S161-S168) or the short intro to this paper to be found here: http://ifors.org/web/ifors-september-2009-newsletter/. Moreover, Journal of Quantitative Analysis in Sports can also be of interest.

Answer (score 4):

**Baseball** fits the criteria of math underlying the game's structure, its optimal and practical strategies, and the analysis of results and performance.  It certainly fits the criterion of popularity.

Comment: I'd distinguish between "baseball" as played by athletes and "moneyball" as "played" by team owners.  The latter is arguably very mathematical, but the former is much less so.

Answer (score 3):

[Heads or Tails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heads_or_Tails) - Is it popular game? There is a lot of mathematics related with this game. For example, it's non-transitive variant - [Penney's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game).

Comment: Obverse or reverse!

Answer (score 3):

There is the amazing set of one-player games presented by S. Tatham (especially loopy and towers):

[https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/puzzles/)

You should try it !

Damien.

Answer (score 3):

The two-player single suit whist has been analyzed completely in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.37236/1940) by Johan Wastlund. This was mentioned by Alison Miller in her answer to my [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64525) *Bridge game with only one suit: strategy*.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be a real game! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whist

Answer (score 2):

Untangle (available in Debian based distros and [*easy* online HTML5 version](http://duketek.com/apps/untangle/)

From the documentation:

> You are given a number of points, some of which have lines drawn between them. You can move the points about arbitrarily; your aim is to position the points so that no line crosses another.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit surprised that [Dominion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominion_%28card_game%29) has not been mentioned yet. I am referring less to the gameplay itself rather than to the analyzes that people do in order to assess the "intrinsic worth" or "situational worth" (my terms) of a card or a strategy, using a [rather complicated simulator](https://dominionsimulator.wordpress.com/). I perceive it as a kind of Monter Carlo analysis.

Comment: What is mathematical about Dominion?

Comment: @TimothyChow: I added a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There are various map/graph colouring games which are more subtle than determining the chromatic number. For example take a planar graph or map (particular or restricted to some category) - how many colours can P1 force P2 to use: or who wins if the first person forced to use a fifth colour loses?

Answer (score 0):

Just a two cents worth here. :)
Chess itself might perhaps not be too mathematical, but the chess evaluation functions of any chess-playing computer program seems like a mathematical object. After all, these are maps from the set of chess positions to $\mathbb{R}$ and they are bound to satisfy various properties. Given any two chess programs that are both strong and might be expected to be decent (in terms of current technology) approximations to objective truth, one might probably expect them to be "close" in some meaningful way that one could perhaps attempt to define.

Comment: In some games, computer programs evaluate positions, and choose to play the position with the highest evaluation, perhaps among a restricted set of candidates. Backgammon is an example. However, many competitive chess programs don't fit this description. Instead of evaluating positions they often directly choose the move to make, based on partial searches of the game tree that are affected by the amount of time left. A computer might try to spend ten seconds, quitting early if it finds a mate, but otherwise reporting its best candidate after that time. This might not be repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

Blood Bowl!  All about managing probability. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_bowl

Answer (score 0):

Othello, since the number of the opponent's pieces you can flip highly depends on where you put yours.

Comment: What gives a mathematician an advantage when playing or studying Othello over an equally smart engineer or philosopher? I learned to play Othello at a decent level to win a multi-game tournament, and I don't recall anything standing out. The moves don't commute, unlike in Lights Out, and the endgame seems to require a brute-force search. If you look at the opening heuristic of trying to minimize your exposed pieces, this could resemble games in combinatorial game theory.

Answer (score 0):

*Spot it!* or *Dobble* (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobble) is a game with 57 cards, each showing 8 symbols. For every pair of cards, there is exactly one common symbol. This is possible because of the projective plane with the cards as points and the common symbols as lines, and it is 57=8^2-8+1.

Answer (score -1):

Being a mathematician allows you to play the game of chess better.

Mathematicians perform calculations quickly and accurately. Mathematicians are creative. Mathematicians are good at identifying the important component to a problem. Mathematicians are accustomed to encountering new problems and challenges. Mathematicians are good at comparing alternatives.

Now consider the game of chess. At any level 90%+ of chess games end as a result of an oversight in calculation. This often happens because one misses a surprising or unconventional move that requires creativity. In chess there are many strategic components, pawn structure, piece activity, material imbalance, king safety etc. but often one of these takes center stage. Almost always in a game of chess there will be a situation you have never encountered before. 90+% of grandmaster chess moves would be listed in the top 5 choices of any tournament player but consistently play the third or fourth choice move is a recipe for disaster even in scholastic chess.

I can not think of a profession better suited to playing chess than that of mathematician!

Comment: Yes, and few mathematicians rise above B class. Sad.

Comment: Well I stopped playing chess, being a student, because I wasn't good, just medium. It depressed me and followed me until now. If I wasn't good at chess how can I hope to be good in math. I'm very happy that Douglas Zare doesn't put chess in mathematical games :-)) 

Comment: In tournament chess, there is time pressure, which is not the normal way to do mathematics, but is common in other professions which require consistency, creativity, and pattern recognition, but not mathematical abstraction. Other professions require a competitive element which is optional or subdued in mathematics. I am not sure, but I believe there is an anti-correlation between chess and mathematics in some populations. Which mathematicians are also chess grandmasters (which would put them in about the top 1000 chess players)?

Comment: The best mathematician chess players in history are:
Emmanuel Lasker
John Nunn (who appears to have published in "Topology" as J. D. M. Nunn).
There are some people who were strong masters once upon a time (Sarnak,Formanek)
I don't agree with Doug's claim that time pressure is the culprit (many good mathematicians were good at mathematics contests), but the real point (imho) is that the amount of self-discipline and effort needed to become a strong tournament chess player is much greater than the intrinsic interest of the game (if you want to work that hard, why not work on mathematics?

Comment: I've never seen much of a relationship between mathematics and chess. I was never any good at chess. I can lose against people in the very game in which I teach them how to play. Completing a PhD in mathematics was pretty trivial by comparison. I also find mathematics well motivated and beautiful. I could never get interested in an arbitrary (and IMHO ugly) set of rules.

Comment: Well, in my college chess teams, most of the chess players were studying mathematics or computer science; but it was very noticeable that the best mathematicians were only average chess players, and vice versa, with few exceptions. (And, several of the top mathematicians didn't play at all).

Former World Chess Champion Karpov gave up mathematics at university because mathematics and chess were "incompatible".

These are not statistically significant samples, of course!

Comment: Former world champion Dr. Botvinnik was also an electrical engineer.

Comment: Former world champion Dr. Euwe was a mathematician and a computer scientist.

Answer (score -1):

Has no one mentioned Finchley Central and the other games discussed in Volume 3 (1969) of Manifold? Available [here](https://ianstewartjoat.weebly.com/manifold-3.html), starting on page 31.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the payoffs of that game. Is/was it popular?

Comment: Variants of Finchley Central have been popular, e.g., Mornington Crescent, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mornington_Crescent_(game). "Finchley Central and Mornington Crescent became popular in the United Kingdom as a play-by-mail pastime, and in the 1980s were played by post in a number of play-by-mail magazines. One format involved a series of elimination rounds, with everyone except the winner of the current round going forward onto the next. Mornington Crescent is now played widely online, in the spirit of the radio series. Games are played by fans on Usenet, in diverse web forums, and ...

Comment: "...on the London Underground itself. A Facebook application has also been produced." The game has also been compared to the game, World War Three (see, e.g., http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmt6jrp/personal/quintics.html).

Comment: Although I do like Mornington Crescent, it really doesn't count because it doesn't actually have any rules - there is no mathematics involved.  You might as well suggest Numberwang.

Comment: @Nate, I'm not familiar with Numberwang, but here are the rules for Finchley Central:  "Players take turns to name London Underground stations: the first one to say ``Finchley Central'' wins."

Comment: @GerryMyerson: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=numberwang

Answer (score -2):

Games are mathematical.  That's not something you can avoid.  If there are rules for moves and goal states, you've already entered mathematics through logic and proof theory.  And even for the simplest games, there is a rich mathematical theory studying it's structure and analysing results.

Mathematicians aren't just interested in finding optimal strategy and assigning a solution to a game.  They also look to generalise and abstract theories of the gameplay and find ways to evaluate statements in the ontology of the game.  Even simple games have rich logical calculi, and there are questions of rule independence and game extensions that can always be asked.

Dynamic Epistemic Logic is one of the general settings in which more advanced theories of game play have been formulated.  Whenever two or more people are involved in gameplay, there are important distinctions between belief, knowledge, shared knowledge, and strategy that must be made to fully understand the dynamics.  DEL (and a number of related settings) have been used to evaluate many common games, from simple pebble and card games to complicated board games and beyond, as a means to understand the evolution of belief systems and evaluate strategy during the play.

[The Dynamic Epistemic Logic of Games](https://projects.illc.uva.nl/lgc/translation/papers/GamesinDEL.pdf)

[Epistemic Logic and the Foundations of Decision and Game Theory](http://olivier.amonbofis.net/docs/logic_decision_and_game_theory_final.pdf)

[Selection Monads and the Relation Between Game Theory and Proof Theory](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Emhe/.talks/mgs2011/escardo-theoretical-mgs2011.pdf)

I think the real mathematical answer to your question, then, is every popular game.  There's no "most mathematical".  Proof theory, models, modal logics, agent calculi and bisimulation lie at the heart of all games.

Comment: How would you start an analysis of the party game Charades?  Gerhard "Or Worse Yet, Of Pictionary" Paseman, 2013.01.30

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Pattern recognition and the theory of images is hugely mathematical.  One of my favorite books to refer to on the subject in college was Monique Pavel's "Fundamentals of Pattern Recognition" which started with the topological theory of images and the group theory of mappings and generalised this to a categorial setting.  Once you have object recognition, then you analyse semantic interpretations and similarity mappings to understand the goals.  Are you suggesting these are things that can't be mathematically modeled, or that they shouldn't be, or?

Comment: I think my point is that some view games mathematically, for the goal of practicing mathematics.  While I understand and often sympathize with such an endeavour, I remind you  that some games are for pure social entertainment, and mathematical analysis is often counter to that goal.  I would consider a semiotic approach to Charades analysis, and I am not clear what goals your suggested approach are trying to reach.  Gerhard "Likes Board Over Party Games" Paseman, 2013.02.01

Comment: The second link is dead - but the paper by Olivier Roy with the title *Epistemic logic and the foundations of decision and game theory* can be [found in various places online](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=Epistemic+Logic+and+the+Foundations+of+Decision+and+Game+Theory).