# Around the Erdős-Ginzburg-Ziv theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

(Here is a problem that emerged in a conversation with [Fedor Petrov](https://mathoverflow.net/users/4312/fedor-petrov) and should really be a sort of "joint posting" if this format were supported.)

---

For any positive integers $k_1\le k_2\le\dotsb\le k_n$, the following two statements are equivalent:

**Statement 1**: Every integer in the range $[0,k_1+\dotsb+k_n]$ is representable as a sum of some of the $k_i$ (without repetitions);

**Statement 2**: Every set of $k_1+\dotsb+k_n$ integers can be partitioned into $n$ subsets such that for each $i\in[n]$, the $i$th subset contains $k_i$ elements and the sum of these elements is divisible by $k_i$.

The equivalence is not difficult to prove using the [Erdős-Ginzburg-Ziv theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Erd%C3%B6s-Ginzburg-Ziv_theorem), but I wonder whether there is a direct combinatorial argument, not appealing to the EGZ explicitly or implicitly, reusing one of its known proofs. Such an argument would result to an alternative proof of the EGZ (known proofs are discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/16721/9924)).

Also, what is the two-dimensional analogue of Statement 1? Is it equivalent to the evident two-dimensional analogue of Statement 2?

Comment: Would you include a more informative title?

Comment: @YCor: I completely agree, but it is difficult to find a short, informative title for this question; I made an attempt, nevertheless.

Comment: Is not the condition $k_{i+1}\leqslant2k_i$ necessary and sufficient?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე the necessary and sufficient condition is $k_1=1$, $k_{i+1}\leqslant 1+k_1+k_2+\ldots+k_i$

Comment: @FedorPetrov Sorry, thanks :)

Comment: possibly Statement 1 has some standard name (like "universal collection of coins" or something like that)

Comment: Prove of the equivalence in the question would imply a proof to the Erdos-Ginzburg-Ziv theorem. So, I'm confused how to treat this question -- does it ask for yet another proof of the Erdos-Ginzburg-Ziv theorem or what?

Comment: Vague idea but maybe you could some how use the lattice of partitions of a set and Moebius inversion on this lattice.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: an ideal answer would lead to another proof of the EGZ, I was the first to mention this.

Comment: Presumably this is the straightforward direction, but for the reference of others, since you don't mention it: Statement 2 implies Statement 1. For $1\leq m\leq K=k_1+\cdots+k_n$, consider the set of $m$ 0s together with $K-m$ many copies of $1$.

Comment: @Seva: Then I'd suggest to review the (ideas behind) known proofs of EGZ, and explain why you think that connection between the two statements would lead to something new. In the current form the question is too vague.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: I added references to a general article about the EGZ,  and also to a MO post with a comparison of the proofs known.